# UPPAAL - force transition with synchro doesn't work

Tags: synchronization, state, modeling, uppaal

Totally stuck on it.
Basically, I have heater, temp sensor and process that simulates rise of temperature.
I want heater to transite to "disabled" state when temp is above some value. It can be synchronised with transition to *abnormal temp* state.
But in simulation I can only **get possibility** to make transition when condition is true.
heater:
[image: heater]
temp riser:
[image: temp riser]
sensor:
[image: sensor]

I tried to add synchro for it like that:
sensor:
[image: sensor]
heater:
[image: heater]
But since it can't change state in automatic mode, the synchro also doesn't work...
How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix specific to this case:

Declare the `disable_heater` as `urgent` and will not allow delay option.

In general this solution is not a good design. The issue is that your model uses asynchronous communication through variables, which introduces many more states and makes it hard to verify. A better option is to use synchronous communication. You are already on your way by using the `disable_heater`, but you also need to synchronize with temp riser through channel, eg `temp_update!`. You will need to synchronize multiple processes so you either link them through urgent or committed location, or use `broadcast` channel (one sender multiple receivers).

Please see Uppaal Tutorial section on value communication.